# How to find all category with the help of attribute for menu purpose in magento?

Tags: magento

I need category list with the help of attribute for creating custom menu visible in all pages.

I can display the attribute on the category page but i need to be able to echo the list on all the pages.

[image]

now i want the category who have product with same attribute.

I have one parent category id

and attribute detail :

Attribute code:
 [image]

attribute value :

[image]

need category list as per attribute id. Means which category product have attribute 0-3 Months, will listed.

Comment: Can you update your question with a little more clarity? It's a little hard to understand what you need

Comment: please check...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Comment: i already post there... http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/137012/how-to-find-all-category-with-the-help-of-attribute-for-menu-purpose-in-magento.
i think question is not up to mark.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
  $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
  $attributes = Mage::getResourceModel('eav/entity_attribute_collection')
                                            ->setEntityTypeFilter($product->getResource()->getTypeId())
                                            ->addFieldToFilter('attribute_code', 'age');
 $attribute = $attributes->getFirstItem()->setEntity($product->getResource());
 $atblist = $attribute->getSource()->getAllOptions(false);
                                        ?>
```

this is for help...

Comment: Can you add more detail that explains how this solves the problem?

Comment: Don't appologise it wasn't critisism, just a recommendaton. Its helpful for other users if you explain your answers in detail so that it is easy to understand what your post means